# Call method of subclass from superclass

Tags: c++, inheritance

Take a look at this sample, there are 3 classes inheriting from `bell`. They overwrite different methods of `bell`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class bell {
public:
    void noise() {
        cout << "dung" << endl;
    }
    void ring() {
        noise();
        noise();
    }
};

class short_bell : public bell {
public:
    void ring() {
        noise();
    }
};

class annoying_bell : public bell {
public:
    void noise() {
        cout << "ding" << endl;
    }
    void ring() {
        noise();
        noise();
        noise();
        noise();
        noise();
    }
};

class slow_bell : public bell {
public:
    void noise() {
        cout << "dooong" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "church bell" << endl;
    bell church_bell;
    church_bell.ring();

    cout << "bicycle bell" << endl;
    short_bell bicycle_bell;
    bicycle_bell.ring();

    cout << "doorbell" << endl;
    annoying_bell doorbell;
    doorbell.ring();

    cout << "school bell" << endl;
    slow_bell school_bell;
    school_bell.ring();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
church bell
dung
dung
bicycle bell
dung
doorbell
ding
ding
ding
ding
ding
school bell
dung
dung
```

Everything works as I expected it but the `school_bell`. `slow_bell` inherits from `bell` and overwrites the `noise` method. When the `ring` method of `slow_bell` is called it falls back to its parent `bell` but when the `ring` method of `bell` calls `noise` it is called the `noise` method of `bell`, instead I want it to call the `noise` method of `slow_bell`.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: *they overwrite different methods of `bell`* **nope** they don't, they merely shadow (or inherit) them. Read a proper introduction to *polymorphism*, in particular the usage of `virtual`, `override`, but also of `=0` and `final`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make them `virtual` and `override` the methods :

Bell:

```
class bell {
public:
    virtual void noise() {
        cout << "dung" << endl;
    }
    void ring() {
        noise();
        noise();
    }
};
```

slow_bell:

```
class slow_bell : public bell {
public:
    void noise() override {
        cout << "dooong" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: I suspect the OP also wanted `ring()` to be polymorphic.